# Continuity in $f:\mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous function.

Prove that $A=[(x,y):||f(x,y)||_2 \in \mathbb{N}]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R} ^2$

Solution: Let $h:\mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ function with $h(x,y)=||(x,y)||_2$ h is continuous obviously. Let $g:\mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$g(x,y)=(hof)(x,y)=h(f(x,y))=||f(x,y)||_2$

g function is continuous since the other 2 are continuous and

$A=[(x,y):g(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}]$

let $(a_n)$ a sequence such that $(a_n) = n$

$A= g^{-1}((a_n))$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$

and because g is continuous and therefore the set composed by the sequence $(a_n)$ is closed.

**Question 1** : Can I put a sequence in a function like i used above? It is the first time i use it like this.

**Question 2**: Is my proof correct? If not i would like you to correct me because im struggling on this one even tho I believe i did a good job.

Comment: Are you *sure* that you want to prove that $A$ is open? Rather than closed?

Comment: small typo sorry about that i obviously wanna prove that the set is closed

Comment: As you saw by the answer below,  in proving things are closed or open and you have a continuous function lying around,  using the fact that inverse images of open or closed stay open or closed is usually the easiest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you you wrote, you use the symbol $n$ for two distinct things. Don't do that.

The set $A$ is closed because:

- your function $g$ is continuous;
- $\Bbb N$ is closed;
- $A=g^{-1}(\Bbb N)$.

Your proof is not correct. A proof along those lines should be as follows: if $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is convergent and each $a_n$ belongs to $A$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ also belongs to $A$.

Comment: My first thought would be to take $A=g^{-1}(\Bbb N)$ but i was not so sure about that. So if i take $A=g^{-1}(\Bbb N)$ instead of the sequence thing my proof should be correct?

Comment: If I would reply “no” to that, then I would be saying that my answer is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Haha thats correct thank you very much that makes my first try of the exercise correct thanks for your time and the effort.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.